# Why are the first 16 bytes wrong with Ruby openssl aes 128 cbc?

Tags: ruby, openssl

I am using OpenSSL in Ruby 1.8.7 and OpenSSL in Bash to decode a file, but with the Ruby code, the first 16 bytes in the decrypted file are wrong.

This is the result I get with Ruby

```
cf e8 cf d1 12 e2 75 48  59 56 30 30 7d 7d 30 1b | wrong bytes
00 00 00 08 00 0c 01 1a  00 05 00 00 00 01 00 00 | good bytes
01 46 01 1b 00 05 00 00  00 01 00 00 01 4e 01 28 | good bytes
********************good bytes****************** | good bytes
```

and this is the result I get with OpenSSL in Bash

```
ff d8 ff e1 22 d2 45 78  69 66 00 00 4d 4d 00 2a | correct bytes
00 00 00 08 00 0c 01 1a  00 05 00 00 00 01 00 00 | same bytes as in Ruby
01 46 01 1b 00 05 00 00  00 01 00 00 01 4e 01 28 | same bytes as in Ruby
*******************a lot of bytes*************** | same bytes as in Ruby
```

Ruby code:

```
require 'openssl'

c = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new("aes-128-cbc")
c.decrypt
c.key = "\177\373\2002\337\363:\357\232\251.\232\311b9\323"
c.iv = "00000000000000000000000000000001"

data = File.read("/tmp/file_crypt")
d = c.update(data)
d << c.final

file = File.open("/tmp/file_decrypt_ruby", "w")
file.write(d)
file.close
```

Bash OpenSSL command:

```
openssl aes-128-cbc -d -in /tmp/file_crypt -out /tmp/file_decrypt_bash -nosalt -iv 00000000000000000000000000000001 -K 7ffb8032dff33aef9aa92e9ac96239d3
```

The encoded file can be downloaded here: http://pastebin.com/EqHfpxjZ.  Use "pbget" (if you have it) to download the file. Otherwise, copy the text, base 64 decode it, and lzma decompress it. (ex. wget -q -O- "$url" | base64 -d | lzma -d > "$TEMP").

Once you have the file through pbget, or the commands above, you'll need to do one final base 64 decoding:

`base64 -d file_encode_base64 > encrypted_file`

To make sure you have the correct encrypted file, the MD5 hash is: `30b8f5e7d700c108cd9815c00ca1de2d`.

If you use the Bash version of OpenSSL to decode this file, you obtain a picture in JPG format.

But if you use the Ruby version you obtain a data file different than picture.jpg by the first 16 bytes.

For reference, this is the command I used to encrypt the file in the first place:

```
openssl aes-128-cbc -e -in picture.jpg -out enc_file -nosalt -iv 00000000000000000000000000000001 -K 7ffb8032dff33aef9aa92e9ac96239d3
```

Can anyone explain why I can decode it with OpenSSL in Bash, but get a slightly different result when I use Ruby?

Comment: Thank you very much gtrig. Please see my new edit.

Comment: Thank gtrig I don't have this MD5 hash see my new edit please.

Comment: Ok, I have the correct files now.  For anyone else looking into this, pbget actually does a few things.  First it does a wget on the URL, then it does a base64 decode, then it does an lzma decompression.  Ex. wget -q -O- "$url" | base64 -d | lzma -d > "$TEMP".  So if you grab the text on pastebin, you need to base64 decode it, lzma decompress it, and base64 decode it again to get the encrypted file mentioned in the question.  It sounds like you used pbput to upload the encrypted file.  In that case, you do not need to base64 encode it before using pbput.  pbput does that for you already.

Comment: I can now duplicate what you are seeing.  One interesting thing about the first 15 bytes of the decrypted files is that they are exactly different by either 0x10 or 0x30 for each byte.  And when there are repeated bytes in the first 15, there are corresponding repeated bytes in the other.  I don't know if this is just coincidence or if it is a clue to what the problem is.

Comment: Thank gtrig. See my edit please. (line 10 is this : encrypted = cipher.update(data) + cipher.final)

Comment: I finally figured out what is wrong.  Your IV needs to be converted to binary.  See my answer for the details.

Comment: Thank you very much gtrig your code work very well.

Comment: If it's working, feel free to click and accept the answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

Finally, it works!  And the answer is actually simple.  Your IV needs to be converted to binary in the Ruby code, similar to how you converted the key.  I found the conversion code and explanation in a comment on this [page](http://www.dzone.com/snippets/encrypting-data-ruby-and).

Try this code:

```
require 'openssl'

cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new("aes-128-cbc")
cipher.decrypt
cipher.key = "7ffb8032dff33aef9aa92e9ac96239d3".unpack('a2'*16).map{|x| x.hex}.pack('c'*16)
cipher.iv  = "00000000000000000000000000000001".unpack('a2'*16).map{|x| x.hex}.pack('c'*16)
data = File.read("/tmp/file_crypt")
decrypted = cipher.update(data) + cipher.final
file = File.open("/tmp/file_decrypt_ruby", "w")
file.write(decrypted)
file.close
```